# How to get table name from SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like below which contains multiple SQL queries and I wanted to extract tables from those queries

[Expected input table contains SQL queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtaeF.png)

[Expected output to extract tables from SQL queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIV3F.png)

I am unable to extract this. Can anyone help with this?

| Queries |
| --- |
| SELECT ProductName FROM dbo.Products WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM sales.OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10); |
| SELECT City FROM cst.Customers UNION ALL SELECT City FROM sup.Suppliers ORDER BY City; |
| SELECT p.id FROM dbo.Person p |
| SELECT t1.dfid, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.downloads_downloads t1 INNER JOIN dbo.downloads_downloads t2 ON t1.dmid = t2.dmid |

Expected output

| Table Name |
| --- |
| dbo.Products, sales.OrderDetails |
| cst.Customers, sup.Suppliers |
| dbo.Person, dbo.address, dbo.address_type, dbo.option, add.option_address_type |
| dbo.downloads_downloads |

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: So are you queries actually stored as a string in a column?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77830237/pass-column-name-which-contains-sql-query-to-sp-describe-first-result-set

Comment: Yes, I am looking to extract tables from string stored in a column.

Comment: In above example you have mentioned is for one string but i need to pass column

Comment: Are you sure you read it? The link I posted above reads the data from a column

Comment: You can only extract the tables that participate in the column being returned, not the tables in the join. For that part, you need to create a view from your query and then check the dependency system views

Comment: if I pass 'select query from SQLqueryDrtails' at the place of 'select 1 as test' then I am getting the SQLqueryDrtails table details while I need to extract tables from sql query stored in query column of SQLqueryDrtails table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a potential solution that probably gets you 80% there:

```sql
/*
create table products (productname nvarchar(10), productid INT)
create table orderdetails (quantity int)
create table customers (city nvarchar(100))
create table suppliers (city nvarchar(100))
create table Person (id int)
create table downloads_downloads (dfid int, dmid int)
*/
DROP TABLE #t
SELECT  *, cast(NULL AS nvarchar(max)) AS tablesOutput
INTO #t
FROM
(
    VALUES  (N'SELECT ProductName FROM dbo.Products WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM dbo.OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10)')
    ,   (N'SELECT City FROM dbo.Customers UNION ALL SELECT City FROM dbo.Suppliers ORDER BY City')
    ,   (N'SELECT p.id FROM dbo.Person p')
    ,   (N'SELECT t1.dfid, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.downloads_downloads t1 INNER JOIN dbo.downloads_downloads t2 ON t1.dmid = t2.dmid group by t1.dfid')
) t (Queries)

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)
,   @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
,   @cols INT
,   @tables_output NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE cr_x CURSOR local FOR
    SELECT  Queries
    FROM    #t
    FOR UPDATE
OPEN cr_x
WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    FETCH next FROM cr_x INTO @query
    IF @@fetch_status <> 0
        BREAK

    -- Get number of columns from query...
    SELECT  @cols = COUNT(*)
    FROM    sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@query, N'', 0)    x
    -- Assume success here, build a view and get references...

    DECLARE @view_name SYSNAME = 'vw_' + REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '-', '_')
    SET @sql = N'
        create view ' + QUOTENAME(@view_name) + N' AS 
            SELECT  *
            FROM    (
            ' + replace(
                    replace(REPLACE(@query, 'select ', 'select top 100 percent '), 'select  ', 'select top 100 percent ') -- Remove this part if order by can be removed
            , '''', '''''') + '
            ) x (' + stuff((
                    SELECT  TOP (@cols) ',[' + cast(row_number() OVER(ORDER BY @@spid) AS nvarchar(max)) +']'
                    FROM    sys.objects so CROSS apply sys.columns sc CROSS apply sys.columns sc2
                    FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
            + ')'
    --PRINT @sql
    BEGIN TRAN
    
    EXEC    sp_executesql @sql
    -- Get our references before rollback
    SELECT  @tables_output = stuff((
        SELECT  ',' + ISNULL(referenced_schema_name + '.', '') + referenced_entity_name
        FROM    sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
        WHERE   referencing_id = object_id(@view_name)
        FOR xml path(''), type
        ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

    ROLLBACK TRAN
    
    UPDATE  #t
    SET tablesOutput = @tables_output
    WHERE   CURRENT OF CR_X
END

CLOSE cr_x
DEALLOCATE cr_x

SELECT  *
FROM    #t
```

The main idea is, convert the sql into a view, which then allows us to extract the table dependencies.
Now, there are a couple of problems:

1. This code doesn't handle `;` at the end of the queries, so these have to be removed
2. To hack around `ORDER BY` which cannot appear in subqueries, i manually insert `TOP 100 PERCENT` after each select. This operation can fail if top already exist in the query, or if your query uses SELECT\n or SELECT\r\n. The easiest is for you to remove the order by's from the queries yourself.
3. CTE queries won't work as well as probably a bunch of other things, but that's life.

This code outputs:

| Queries | tablesOutput |
| --- | --- |
| SELECT ProductName FROM dbo.Products WHERE ProductID = ANY (SELECT ProductID FROM dbo.OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10) | dbo.OrderDetails,dbo.Products |
| SELECT City FROM dbo.Customers UNION ALL SELECT City FROM dbo.Suppliers ORDER BY City | dbo.Customers,dbo.Suppliers |
| SELECT p.id FROM dbo.Person p | dbo.Person |
| SELECT t1.dfid, COUNT(*) FROM dbo.downloads_downloads t1 INNER JOIN dbo.downloads_downloads t2 ON t1.dmid = t2.dmid group by t1.dfid | dbo.downloads_downloads |

If you're not interested in *all* tables and only want the table source of the columns being outputted, you can use the solution from the linked question.